# How to build a hot swap server using Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, failover

I have a requirement wherein we have to provide servers with hotswap, i.e. 2 redundant servers running a set of applications and database (MySQL in this case) and one should take control when the other fails. After the defunct server is restored, the database should be automatically synchronised. I want to do this using Linux OS and preferably ubuntu or fedora.

Can someone provide me links, where can I get started.

Comment: This isn't hot-swap - hot-swap refers to being able to replace components of a single server without poweroff. This sounds like high-availability failover.

Comment: Thanks bdonlan for the correction, failover was the thing I really meant.

Answer (score 3):

As bdonlan stated, what you want is high-availability (HA) failover.  You can learn about HA with linux at

- www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page
- www.linuxvirtualserver.org
- www.redhat.com/software/rha/cluster

More importantly, you will need to failover your MySQL database.  This gets to be very complex with things such as how you plan the data replication between your nodes.  Read up on MySQL cluster and MySQL replication

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html